# Trying to store 32-bit number across 2 16-bit registers

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

This is for the 8086, and I am using NASM.

I have HW I've been struggling with, where I am supposed to accept a 32-bit binary number as input, store it in register pair `dx:bx`, and output the number to the screen.

I have a problem I haven't been able to fix for a long time. Instead of outputting the 32 bits that were entered, it is outputting the last 16 bits that were entered, and doing it twice.

Could someone please look at this and help me understand why I am not getting the whole 32-bit number?

```
    CPU 286
    org 100h

section .data
    prompt: db  "Please enter a binary number: $"
    msg: db 0Dh,0Ah, "The number you entered is:    $"

section .text   
start:  
    mov ah,9        ; load print function
    mov dx,prompt   ; load prompt to print
    int 21h         ; prompt for input

    mov bx,0        ; bx holds input value
    mov dx,0        ; clear dx
    mov ah,1        ; input char function
    int 21h         ; read char into al

; loop to accept and store input
input:  
    cmp al,0Dh      ; is char = CR?
    je  outputMsg   ; yes?  finished with input
    shl bx,1        ; bx *= 2, shifts msb of BX into CF
    rcl dx,1        ; rotate CF into lsb of DX
    and al,01h      ; converts ASCII to binary value
    or  bl,al       ; "adds" the input bit
    int 21h         ; read next character
    jmp input       ; loop until done

outputMsg:  
    mov ah,9        ; load print function
    mov dx,msg      ; load output message to print
    int 21h         ; print output message

; loop to load either '0' or '1' to print, depending on carry flag
    mov cx, 32      ; loop counter
output: 
    rol bx,1        ; rotate msb into CF
    jc  one         ; if CF is 1, go to "one" loop
    mov dl,'0'      ; of CF is 0, set up to print '0'
    jmp print       ; jump to "print" loop
one:    
    mov dl,'1'      ; set up to print '1'
print:  
    mov ah,2        ; load print char fcn
    int 21h         ; print char
    loop output     ; go to next character



Exit:
    mov ah,04Ch     ;DOS function: Exit program
    mov al,0        ;Return exit code value
    int 21h         ;Call DOS.  Terminate program
```

Comment: Because you completely discard the upper bits in dx by using it in int 21h calls and your loop only loops bx and doesn’t care at all about dx in it. You’ll have to actually use the value to print it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thank you!  I did finally get it working thanks to your advice.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> outputMsg:  
>  mov ah,9        ; load print function
>  mov dx,msg      ; load output message to print
>  int 21h         ; print output message
> ```

At the *outputMsg* label, `DX` holds the high word of your 32-bit number in `DX:BX`. By writing `mov dx, msg` you've destroyed it! You need to preserve it.

```
outputMsg:
 push dx
 mov  ah, 09h
 mov  dx, msg
 int  21h
 pop  dx
```

---

> ```
> rol bx,1        ; rotate msb into CF
> ```

The most significant bit (msb) of the 32-bit number in `DX:BX` is bit 15 of `DX`.
The code to retrieve it is:

```
shl  bx, 1     ;Shift low word left, carry gets its highest bit
rcl  dx, 1     ;Bring that carry in high word, carry gets msb
```

---

Your present solution to either output a "0" or a "1" works, but a much cleaner solution does not use the `jc` / `jmp` instructions. Those lead to untidy code requiring a lot of labels!

Adding the value of the carry flag (which is either 0 or 1) to the character "0" wil give you the requested "0" or "1".

```
push dx
mov  dl, '0'
adc  dl, 0      ;The immediate is zero, so only the carry gets added!
mov  ah, 02h
int  21h
pop  dx
```

Because the DOS output function uses `DL`, it was necessary to preserve and restore the high word of the number held in `DX`.

Of course some of the problems with this program would not have existed if the 32-bit number had been stored in some other register pair like `DI:SI` or `BP:BX`. Given that this is HW, `push` / `pop` works.

---

As a final note.

> ```
> mov ah,04Ch     ;DOS function: Exit program
> mov al,0        ;Return exit code value
> ```

When loading 2 byte registers (`AH` and `AL`) that team up in 1 word register (`AX`), you can save on code size and execution speed by combining the loads:

```
mov  ax, 4C00h     ;DOS function: Exit program with exit code 0
```